# Linux Source code location of interface configuration(eth)

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

My requirement is to implement(insert ) an ip address validation step in kernel.. Once any of the interface is up and got ip, then my validation should happen..

So as the first step , in source code (linux 2.6 source code I downloaded ) , in which file I need to trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel is the wrong place for this unless you're doing something embedded with a teeny tiny footprint. What you really want is [ifplugd](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/ifplugd/).

However, if you absolutely insist on having it be in the kernel - take a look at the kernel bits that get enabled when CONFIG_IP_PNP=y

Comment: CONFIG_IP_PNP enables automatic IP configuration in the kernel.

Comment: Hi Nathan  file 'arch/x86/configs/i386_defconfig' contains CONFIR_IP_PNP=y  But again I am bit confused that how to trace further.

Comment: ctags or grep - but honestly, if you're this unfamiliar with how to work with the Linux kernel - you should be doing this in user land with a script. Otherwise you have a long path ahead of you.